# How to click on all the links in a page, one by one with go back?

Tags: vba, hyperlink, back, permission-denied

I have a permission denied error on the If condition on the second loop.

I click on the first url, it opens, I go back, and I want to click on the second url in this page but the error appears.

```
Dim fourdoc As HTMLDocument
Set fourdoc = objIE.document

Dim t As Long, i As Long

Dim delement As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim delements As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Set delements = fourdoc.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each delement In delements
    Do While objIE.Busy Or objIE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    '' error permission denied there second time loop for''
    If delement.ClassName = "dialogUrl aImg" Then

        Do While objIE.Busy Or objIE.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        delement.Click
        Do While objIE.Busy Or objIE.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Set fourdoc = objIE.document
        'here do your stuff within the new url
        objIE.GoBack
        Do While objIE.Busy Or objIE.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Set fourdoc = objIE.document
        Do While objIE.Busy Or objIE.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

    End If
Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you'll need to tackle it a different way, not sure if `delements` will still apply, although the same page, the original `fourdoc` wont be.  Not 100% though.

Comment: Once you navigate away from the page containing the elements referenced by `delements` then those references are no longer valid.  On the second pass you would need to again get that collection of references and count to the second match on the classname, and click that element.  Etc etc

Comment: Thanks, but i'm a novice in VBA... I'm not sure to understand. In this case, could you give me a quick code correction plz ? Thanks so much for your help !

Comment: I have tried several solution with i integer (i=i+1) but it's not working, delement(i).click  generate a error ....

Answer (score 1):

After 24 hours of reflection, I've the solution:

```
Dim fourdoc As HTMLDocument
Set fourdoc = objIE.document

Dim i As Integer
Dim t As Integer

'Dim delement As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim delements As Object
Set delements = fourdoc.getElementsByClassName("dialogUrl aImg")
t = delements.Length
Debug.Print t

For i = 0 To t - 1
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Do While objIE.Busy Or objIE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set fourdoc = objIE.document
    Set delements = fourdoc.getElementsByClassName("dialogUrl aImg")
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Do While objIE.Busy Or objIE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    delements(i).Click
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Do While objIE.Busy Or objIE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    objIE.GoBack
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Do While objIE.Busy Or objIE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Next i
```